# How to prevent the laptop from getting overly hot?

Tags: windows-8.1, cpu, macbook-pro, overheating

I have a MacBookPro 17' circa 2011.  I have Windows 8.1 installed on it.  Over the last year the laptop has started become super hot the moment it does anything slightly intensive.

I understand that the laptop is old but are there any tips I could try?

Comment: Does the same happen with macOS? What have you already tried?

Comment: Using the power saver performance profile will make the laptop generate less heat. Using canned air to clean the vents will usually improve the fans'  ability to cool the laptop. Opening the laptop and removing all the built up dist will improve the laptop's cooling at a small risk of breaking the machine.

Comment: @slhck Not sure.  I have nothing serious installed on the mac partition - just the bare OS.  Anyway to stress it with just that?

Comment: http://osxdaily.com/2012/10/02/stress-test-mac-cpu/

Comment: I'm not that familiar with the internals of macbooks, so forgive me if this easier sad than done. But have you popped it open to see if the fans/air intake grilles are clean from dust and lint?

Comment: look up laptop coolers. They can plug into usb.. your laptop can sit on it and they an blow cool air under it

Comment: @slhck I stressed the macOS side of things. I got hot, but not nearly as hot.  I i think I need to find a way to stress the GPU cause I think Windows utilizes it more than macOS.   Specificaly when I play AOE2, I could probably make scrambled eggs.

Comment: clean the cpu cooler fan